# Application with no connection string - Where is the DB hidden?

Tags: database, entity-framework, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

So, I have created a console application, added the entity framework nuget package, created a dbcontext and enabled migrations for my project.

However, I don't see the database anywhere. The database exists since I can query it when I run the application but since I haven't entered a connection string I don't see it anywhere in my SQL Management Studio.

My question is, where do Visual Studio "hide" this database?

Btw, I'm using EF6 Code First.

EDIT: Here is my app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Check your app.config under the EntityFramework section: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx#Factory

Comment: @SteveGreene
I checked out the article but I don't see anywhere in my app.config file which tells me the location of the database. I have included the app.config file in my original question.

Comment: OK, you are using LocalDb so it won't have a connection string by default. You could add one, but your files will be where T.Rahgooy indicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to constructor of the `context` to see the default connection string used.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Usually it creates the database in `v11.0` or `mssqllocaldb`(in you app.config it is `mssqllocaldb`) instance of `sqllocaldb`.
The database file can be located at `Users` folder(Windows 8.1):

```
 C:\Users\{UserName}\ApplicationName.ContextName.mdf
```

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks a lot!